# Deleting particular data from a json object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am using titanium for developing Android application. I want to delete some data from json object. My json object given below:

```
{"feeds":
[
    {"username":"abc","user":"abc","feed":{"description":"dss","id":660,"user_id":1}},
    {"username":"bcd","user":"bcd","feed":{"description":"dddd","id":659,"user_id":1}}
]
}
```

for receiving json object I used following code

```
var json = this.responseText;
var json = JSON.parse(json);
json.feeds.splice(0,1);
alert(json.feeds[0]);
```

I want to delete particular data from json object like `json.feeds[0]` using JavaScript. I am able to access `json.feeds[0]` but not able to delete. Is there any way to delete that data from json object using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to properly remove an element from a javascript array:

```
json.feeds.splice(0,1)
```

Using the code you've provided it will look like:

```
(function(){
    var json = {
        "feeds": [
            {"username":"abc","user":"abc","feed":{"description":"dss","id":660,"user_id":1}},
            {"username":"bcd","user":"bcd","feed":{"description":"dddd","id":659,"user_id":1}}
        ]
    };

    json.feeds.splice(0,1);
    console.log(json.feeds); // just to check that "feeds" contains only a single element
})();
```

Comment: thank u for quick replay. I tried this but it not working.it not deleting data from json object. I also tried **delete json.feeds[0]** but that also not working

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working snippet based on your input. Is it what you are actually want to achieve?

Comment: thank you for reply.I have updated my code in question.plz check it's not working as required.

Comment: Actually, it is. As your array in question contains two elements, after deleting the first one, the second one is shifted and becomes the first. I.e. initially you have `json.feeds[0]` and `json.feeds[1]`, after splice the first one is deleted and the second one is shifted. That still allows you to access `json.feeds[0]`, however, that will be the element that was initially the second. The first one has gone.

You'd better check `json.feeds.length` for array length before and after splice operation.

Comment: You are telling as I required.But after splice it showing me 0th position element not 1st position element and also not changing length.i.e. it remain 2. is there any problem in my json object? I can also modify the field in the data but only can't delete it.

Comment: I suggest you have a closer look at your code. You could try executing the sample I've provided previously and check it's working as expected. You could also try checking splice command return value, as it should return the item removed from the array.

Answer (score 3):

1. Parse the JSON into a JavaScript data structure
2. Use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the elements you don't want from the array
3. Serialise the JavaScript objects back into JSON