# Delete property by value

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
var names = { 45: "Jeff", 145: "Peter", 11: "Dandie", 879: "Michael" }
```

How do I remove "Peter" from the object?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20remove%20element%20from%20object

Comment: That's _Javascript_.  It has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695746/deleting-particular-data-from-a-json-object-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
delete names['145'];
```

or

```
delete names.145;
```

Comment: wt is my answer shows?

Comment: The second one throws a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

The code is bad practice, the keys and values are in the wrong order. Try the following to achieve what you want:

```
for(var key of Object.keys(names))
    if(names[key]=='John')
         delete names[key];
```

Without for .. of:

```
Object.keys(names).forEach(function(key){
    if(names[key]=='John')
         delete names[keys];
});
```

Comment: `for...of` doesn't exist in most implementations yet. If you have an array, use a normal `for` loop.

Comment: How is that a reason to downvote my answer. This isn't an array, it's an Object

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your answer (how can I?). But I can understand the downvote. Personally I'd find an answer that doesn't work in 99% for all environments "not useful".

Comment: I've added an alternative. btw, 99% of all environments include ie 6.

Comment: Well, you must agree that using a feature which is not implemented in any browser yet is not really helpful. On the other hand, a solution that works in all browser but IE6 is useful.

Comment: It has been implemented in firefox for a long time. But I agree with you on IE6.